# Using IF in SELECT statement of Google Sheets Query

Tags: if-statement, select, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In order to provide relevant data to an accounting person for him to work further in the Bill Booking stage from a master sheet that I manage in Google Sheets, the query function needs to satisfy either of the two conditions.

The master sheet is here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pY53-XaGnUQ3BPmLh90mLSqIwSo7S2_QOPbD6JBQHOA/edit#gid=0

Two conditions for an accounting person to see what he needs to work on is
(if either of the mentioned two conditions is fulfilled, the data needs to be shown)

1. If Col8 = "Yes" and Col14 = "Done"
2. If Col8 = "No" and Col11 = "Done"

For this, I have tried the following

```
Ifna(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pY53-XaGnUQ3BPmLh90mLSqIwSo7S2_QOPbD6JBQHOA/edit#gid=0","Master!A3:N")," Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col7 "&IF(OR(AND(COL8 = "Yes", COL14 = "Done"), AND(COL8 = "No", COL11 = "Done")))&" "))
```

Currently, this is not showing me any data and without any error. However, it should show him 3 data to work on.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the AND and OR directly into the query like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pY53-XaGnUQ3BPmLh90mLSqIwSo7S2_QOPbD6JBQHOA/edit#gid=0","Master!A3:N")," Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col7,Col8,Col11,Col14 where Col8='Yes' and Col14='Done' or Col8='No' and Col11='Done' ")
```

[image]

If you take the IFNA out of the original query, you can see that there is an error because the If statement delivers #N/A. The reason why the If statement delivers #N/A is that there is no second argument to the if statement.

If you reduce the If statement to

```
=OR(AND(COL8 = "Yes", COL14 = "Done"), AND(COL8 = "No", COL11 = "Done"))
```

it always delivers FALSE because COL8, COL11 and COL14 are valid cell references, but point to blank cells outside the range of the current sheet so it still doesn't work.